# large file upload to Azure blob handling in node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, node.js-stream

My goal is to upload a large file(any file type) it into Azure blob.

I want to follw below 2 approaches.

```
1. Convert file into stream and upload into Azure blob
2. Convert file into block streams and commit all the blocks to Azure blob in parallel
```

I am using Node.js Azure blob service API's

Approach 1:
    I am converting my file into `ReadStream` by using `fs.createReadStream(fileName, 'utf-8')`. And uploading that stream into Azure blob using `blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream()`.
Below is sample code for this approach

```
    var blobName = "azure-blob-name.doc";
    var fileSize = fs.statSync(fileName).size;
    var readableStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName, 'utf-8');
        blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(containerName, blobName, readableStream, fileSize, function (error, result, response) { 
            if(error) console.log(error);
            console.log({message : "blob uploaded"});
        });
```

Approach 2:
    I want to convert the `ReadStream` into azure blob blocks by using `blobService.createBlockFromStream()` and commit all the blocks in parallel. How can I achieve this approach?

Below is the sample code I am trying to do, But it ends up throwing an error

```
var fileName = "local-file-path/filename.doc";
    var blobName = "azure-blob-name.doc";
    var fileSize = fs.statSync(fileName).size;
    var readableStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName, 'utf-8');
    var bl=1;
    var blockIds = [];
    readableStream.on("data", function (chunk) {
        var blockId = 'block'+bl;
        bl++;
        blobService.createBlockFromStream(blockId, containerName, blobName, chunk, chunk.length, function(error, response){
            if(error) console.log(error);

            blockIds.push(blockId);
                    console.log({message : "block created"});
        });
    });
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
    D:\main-workspace\file-management\node_modules\azure-storage\lib\common\services\storageserviceclient.js:522
                body.outputStream.on('open', function () {
                                  ^
    TypeError: body.outputStream.on is not a function
```

1. Approach 1 working fine but taking too much time to upload. (Stats: took 80 seconds to upload 40 MB file).
2. Is my 2nd approach is the correct one to improve the performance? If yes, how can I achieve this approach?

Is there a better way to improve performance? Any suggestions on this front?

Apart form Azure blob service API's is any other way we can do this? My goal is to upload any type of large file in less time. For example that 40 MB file should have to upload in 20 seconds.

Please drive me in the right direction. Thanks for the responses in advance.

**Edit - Updated the code**

@Gaurav

Below is my updated code. But my `readableStream.on("end", function(){})` is never getting called to commit the blocks. In my Azure account, the file is getting creating but with the 0 bytes

```
      const stream = require('stream');
      var fileName = "local-file-path/filename.doc";
      var blobName = "azure-blob-name.doc";
      var fileSize = fs.statSync(blobName).size;
      var customBlockSize = 1200; //1.2 MB CAP           
      var NoOfBlocks = Math.ceil(fileSize/customBlockSize);
      var blockIdLength = NoOfBlocks.toString().length;
      var readableStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName, 'utf-8');
      var bl=1;
      var blockIds = [];
      readableStream.on("data", function (chunk) {         
          var blockId = 'block'+ blockGuId(bl, blockIdLength);//Block ids must be of same length
          bl++;
          const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough({
            highWaterMark: chunk.length
          });
          bufferStream.end(chunk);
          blobService.createBlockFromStream(blockId, containerName, blobName, bufferStream, chunk.length, function(error, response){
              if(error) console.log(error);

              blockIds.push(blockId);
              console.log({message : "block ("+blockId+") created"});
          });
      });

      readableStream.on("end", function(){

        console.log('readableStream.on "end"');

        blobService.commitBlocks(containerName, blobName, blockIds, function(error, result){
          if(error) console.log(error);

          console.log({message : "all blocks uploaded"});
          var hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart)
          console.info('Execution time (sec ms): %ds %dms', hrend[0], hrend[1] / 1000000)
        });
      });

      blockGuId(number, blockIdLength)
      {
        return Array(Math.max(blockIdLength - String(number).length + 1, 0)).join(0) + number;
      }
```

Below is the socket error

```
{ Error: socket hang up at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15) at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:364:25) at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15) at _handle.close (net.js:610:12) at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:386:7) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

What I am missing here? Why the socket error occurs while creating blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code:

```
const stream = require('stream');

var fileName = "local-file-path/filename.doc";
    var blobName = "azure-blob-name.doc";
    var fileSize = fs.statSync(fileName).size;
    var readableStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName, 'utf-8');
    var bl=1;
    var blockIds = [];
    readableStream.on("data", function (chunk) {
        //var blockId = 'block'+bl;
        bl++;
        var blockId = UseGuidHere();//Block ids must be of same length
        const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough({
          highWaterMark: chunk.length
        });
        bufferStream.end(chunk);
        blobService.createBlockFromStream(blockId, containerName, blobName, bufferStream, chunk.length, function(error, response){
            if(error) console.log(error);

            blockIds.push(blockId);
                    console.log({message : "block created"});
        });
    });
```

As mentioned in the code, please assign a GUID for your block id as the block ids must be of same length. With your current logic, after 9 blocks the length of your block id will change and that will cause a failure in the upload process.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I have tried by assigning proper block id with the same length, most of the blocks are created successfully, but some blocks end up throwing an error below 

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:364:25)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at _handle.close (net.js:610:12)
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:386:7) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

I am posting my entire updated code as an answer

Comment: Are you running this code against a real account or storage emulator? Where are you getting this socket error?

Comment: I'm running on real azure account only. While creating a block I am getting this for some blocks, not for all the blocks. `blobService.createBlockFromStream()` this method returning this error

Comment: I am not getting this socket error now. But unable to upload the content of the file. `readableStream.on("end", function(){})` is calling before the blocks creation. how can I commit after all the blocks created?

Comment: Below is the response I am getting after creating a block `
{ isSuccessful: true,
  statusCode: 201,
  body: '',
  headers:
   { 'content-length': '0',
     'content-md5': '/ojxJQarcJVJFWo29DchCQ==',
     server: 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
     'x-ms-request-id': '483928ab-c01e-003a-5344-48a308000000',
     'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28',
     'x-ms-request-server-encrypted': 'true',
     date: 'Thu, 01 Aug 2019 08:41:19 GMT' },
  md5: undefined,
  requestServerEncrypted: true }` . That means empty block is getting creatinng. What was the issue here?